# Accessing routing table from agent to get next hop

Tags: groovy, unetstack

I've set up my routing algorithm from node itself. After this I want to send datagrams from physical layer in that route itself.

For example if my routes are 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 and I want to send a datagram from 1 to 3 I want my datagram to go through 2.

For this routing table for 1 will be as follows:

**Routing table for 1**

- to: 3 nextHop: 2
- to: 2 nextHop: 2
- to: 1 nextHop: 1

So I want my process msg function to be as follows:

```
  void processMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg instanceof DatagramNtf && msg.protocol == PING_PROTOCOL && msg.to != nodeInfo.addr)
      def dG = new DatagramReq(to: routes.nextHop(msg.to), destination: msg.to)
      send new DatagramReq(recipient: msg.sender, to: msg.from, protocol: Protocol.DATA)
  }
```

also what routes.nextHop does is takes in the addr of the destination node and from the routing table gets the next hop.

I want to know to how to get the nextHop from routing table.

Answer (score 3):

To send datagrams using route table entries, you need to use `router` agent, which inturn uses `link` and `phy` agents to send your datagram to the destination.Further routing of packets to the destination will be taken care by `router` agent itself.Hence I don't think you need to determine `nextHop` here for the `to` field in `DatagramReq`.

Your `DatagramReq` can be as-

```
router.send new DatagramReq(recipient: msg.sender, to: msg.from, protocol: Protocol.DATA)
```

Assuming `router` is the `AgentID` defined, and value of `msg.from` is your destination, and there is a valid route in the route table.

Further, `nextHop` or `getNextHop()` returns the address of neighbor node.